# Update and reinstalling Mac OS hangs(MBA A1)

Tags: macos, install, big-sur

I tried updating to `Big Sur 11.5` but the machine hung on the Apple logo and the progress bar didn't move at all for probably hour or so. Then I restarted the machine, still didn't budge. I went to recovery mode and ran first aid on the volume and attempted to reinstall Mac OS but again it got hung-up on the apple logo after the installation screen was through. (Also tried unplugging peripherals other than the charger and that did not work as well)

This is really bizarre. As far as I know progress bar shouldn't stay static for hours on end and the fact that it doesn't show any text about what it actually is doing is really problematic as well.

Any ideas, what to do?

EDIT: Just figured out that there’s no way at all to boot in verbose mode on M1.

EDIT: Hangs on subsequent attempts to reinstall as well.

EDIT: Did SMC reset, ran `diskutil repairdisk` on all Volumes and it still hangs. I am actually in awe how a software update can totally mess up a machine. It's absolutely marvelous.

Comment: Do you have a backup?

Comment: @bmike No I don’t.

Comment: @CupOfGreenTea After backing up your files as bmike suggests, reboot into verbose mode (CMD+V on startup) and take a slow-mo video of the process. Upload the screencaps (to www.PasteBin.com or equivalent) and update your question with the link so that we can examine the console log and try to understand why it's hanging.

Comment: @pion will that work without backing up files to USB?I think backing up files on external storage should be last ditch attempt.

Comment: @CupOfGreenTea It’s by no means a “last ditch attempt” - having a current backup should always be standard practice if your data is important to you. But if you already ran Disk First Aid and it didn’t find any errors, the chances of you accidentally losing data are low, so you can skip that step for now.

Comment: @CupOfGreenTea If your files doesn't matter (or the essentials are icloud-backed) then just run internet recovery and do as it suggests.

Comment: @pion CMD + V doesn’t bring me to verbose mode. I tried nvram boot-args=“-v” but doesn’t run in verbose mode afterwards as well. The command appearantly needs prefixing with sudo but for sudo says command not found.

Comment: @CupOfGreenTea Are you holding it from before power-on and continuing to hold? `sudo` is not available because it's not needed in recovery mode (you are already root). You're likely unable to set boot-args because you have SIP enabled. Try disabling SIP, rebooting, and re-running `nvram`. Finally, verbose mode exists only in the kernel and in efiboot, so if you're stuck in UEFI, that's why you're seeing the progress bar and no console text.

Comment: @pion I hold CMD V before and I continue to hold it. The command nvram boot-args=“-v” seems to run fine and when i type nvram-bootargs it confirms the -v. However no verbose mode after reboot. I dont think there’s verbose mode at all for M1 models.

Comment: How full is the drive?

Answer (score 1):

The first order of business would be to boot to target disk mode and make a backup of any key files or see if safe mode let’s you connect a USB drive.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262

If that fails, I might call Apple for triage assistance. They would know if and when the 11.5.1 full installer is released and try again perhaps?

If multiple reinstalls all hang, the erase install is the next option short of getting someone skilled at reading the boot logs or install logs (to see what step hangs) as alternatives to entering hardware repair.

- https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208496

Comment: But reinstalling Mac OS from recovery shouldn’t normally cause problems.

Comment: No, it’s designed to fix minor issues and not delete any data. I added why back up is prudent as an edit here to my answer @CupOfGreenTea so you can [follow my reasoning](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/414604/5472).